# Regarding initialization in the main method

Tags: java, class

So lets say there's a class SimpleGame with main method(slick2d btw):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SlickException {
    AppGameContainer app = new AppGameContainer(new SimpleGame());
```

Let's say this class has many initialization going on in the class fields declaration,
wouldn't it do many unnecessary classes and fields?

I saw a lot of code use this and I never understood that.

Comment: I mean it creates itself in main method, that class has a lot of fields, wouldn't there be alot of unnecessary fields??

Comment: If there's a lot of initialization going on, why would you think it unnecessary? Either the fields are necessary, or they're not - creating an instance from main is somewhat separate to that. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ***wouldn't it do many unnecessary classes and fields?***

No, since the `main` method is `static`, no fields are initialized just by starting the application.

You could imagine doing something like `new AppGameContainer(this)`, but as you probably know, the `this` reference is not available in static methods.

The reason to just do something like `new AppGameContainer(new SimpleGame())` in the main method is to "escape" the static context, and to get hold of a proper instance with fields etc. (All fields would otherwise have to be static too, which is considered bad practice.)